# Compaq SmartArray 5300 controllers - how to recreate logical volume without data loss?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, hp

My company owns an old server Proliant ML370 G2 on which we had all of our web logs. But one disk of the Smart Array 5300 v1.76 crashed, with it the whole server (????). But then on the Smart Array manager, after a reboot, there was no more Logical Volume.
So my question is, could I recreate a logical volume, without erasing all the data from the disks, so I could copy them?

If not, by mounting the 3 hard drives on a linux server, is there a way to simulate a SmartArray and create cciss device?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just restore from your backups. That will be a lot more simple than trying to kluge together this ancient array. If you don't have backups, then cut your losses and send the drives to a professional data recovery shop. Be prepared to pay dearly for their services.

Comment: Whoa, unless I'm mistaken, the SA 5300 was released in 2001. No wonder it failed. Don't even consider putting that card back into use.

Answer (score 1):

Nah... this probably won't work. HP Smart Array controllers store the array metadata on the drive. But perhaps during the failure, the logical drive was faulted entirely.

A single disk failure should not cause data loss, **unless** the array was configured in RAID 1.

**Was this array configured in RAID 0?**

If so... well, the data is gone. If not, try powering the server off and removing the power cables. Let it sit for a few minutes, then plug them back in.

Follow the system's boot prompts very carefully, as you may be asked whether to enable or disable the logical drive. You will likely want to press `F2` at this prompt. See if this works...

Comment: Why would you lose data in a single-drive failure on RAID 1? Unless you mean RAID0..